# Proof of Brouwer's Fixed Point Theorem using Stokes' Theorem

Tags: differential-geometry, fixed-point-theorems, stokes-theorem

There is a proof of Brauwer's fixed point theorem (for functions $f:\overline{D(0,1)}\subset\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow \overline{D(0,1)}$), it appears in several sources including the [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brouwer_fixed-point_theorem#A_proof_using_homology).
The idea is to construct a smooth function $r:\overline{D(0,1)}\rightarrow S^{n-1}$ such that $r|_{S^{n-1}}=Id$ : You assuming that $f$ has no fixed point, and let r(x) be the intersection point of the continuation of the line $[x,f(x)]$ with $S^{n-1}$ on the side of x. Showing it's smooth is not a big deal since $r(x)$ is of the form $r(x)=f(x)+\lambda(x-f(x))$ for $\lambda\geq 1$ and it clearly maps every point on $S^{n-1}$ to itself.

Then you take a volume $\omega$ form on $S^{n-1}$, and consider the pullback $r^*\omega$ and say that on one hand we have: $$0\underset{\text{volume form}}{<}\int_{S^{n-1}}\omega=\int_{S^{n-1}}{r|_{S^{n-1}}}^*\omega$$ and on the ohter hand: $$\int_{S^{n-1}}{r|_{S^{n-1}}}^*\omega=\int_{S^{n-1}}r^*\omega\underset{Stokes}{=}\int_\overline{D(0,1)}d(r^*\omega)=\int_\overline{D(0,1)}r^*(d\omega)=0$$ since $\omega$ is a maximal form on $S^{n-1}$, it's exterior derivative $d\omega$ is zero.

We have defined the pullback of a differential form using a smooth function $g:U\rightarrow \mathcal{M}$ for an open set $U\subset{\mathbb{R}^{n-1}}$ by $$g^*\omega(x)(v_1,\dots,v_{n-1})=\omega(g(x))(Dg(x)v_1,\dots,Dg(x)v_{n-1})$$ for any $x\in U$ and any vectors $v_1,\dots,v_{n-1}\in \mathbb{R}^{n-1}$

There is also a pullback with functions between manifolds using the local coordinates so I understand why $\int_{S^{n-1}}\omega=\int_{S^{n-1}}Id^*\omega=\int_{S^{n-1}}{r|_{S^{n-1}}}^*\omega$, but what I don't understand it is why can we say that $\int_{S^{n-1}}{r|_{S^{n-1}}}^*\omega=\int_{S^{n-1}}r^*\omega$ - how does the definition of a pullback by a smooth function extend to the boundry of the open set such that we can say state this equality.

More generally I start to wonder what do we mean when we pull-back differential forms from manifolds with boundry - is it the limit of the pull-backs from the interior, or do we pull them back using the induced atlas on the bounry? If it's the latter, how do we know we're getting a smooth differential form?

Comment: A manifold with boundary $M$ is also defined as the preimage of $[0,\infty)$ under a smooth function $f:M' \to \mathbb{R}$ having $0$ as a regular value, where $M'$ is some "larger" manifold. This definition is equivalent to the usual (having an atlas to $\mathbb{R}^{n}_{+}$), with the bonus that the definition of a smooth function is slightly more obvious - a map $f:M \to N$ between manifolds (possibly with boundary) is smooth if it can extended to a smooth $f:M'\to N'$. $Df$ at the boundary is independent of choice of extension, which also lets us define pullbacks in a meaningful way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $N\subset M$ is a (let's say) compact $k$-dimensional submanifold, let $\iota\colon N\to M$ be the inclusion map. Then when $\omega$ is a $k$-form on $M$, we have $\int_N \omega = \int_N \iota^*\omega$.

In the case you're asking about, $N=S^{n-1}$ and $M=D^n$. Since $r\circ\iota = \text{id}_{S^{n-1}}$ (by definition of a retraction),
$$\int_{S^{n-1}}\omega = \int_{S^{n-1}}\text{id}^*\omega = \int_{S^{n-1}}(r\circ\iota)^*\omega = \int_{S^{n-1}}\iota^*r^*\omega=\int_{S^{n-1}}r^*\omega.$$

Comment: I've seen a similar answer on a different thread, so I'll ask more specifically - how is $r^*\omega$ defined at the boundary of $D^n$? If you claim that $r^*\omega|_{S^{n-1}}=i^*r^*\omega$ why is $r^*\omega$ continuous when you don't necessarily have that $lim_{x\rightarrow S^{n-1}} Dr(x)=I$?

Comment: First, your question doesn't make sense (as $r\colon D^n \to S^{n-1}$). Second, I should have said that $\omega|_N = \iota^\omega$ point by point, by definition. But you need to look at charts when you want to differentiate maps on manifolds with boundary; one checks once and for all that if $f\colon\Bbb H^k\to\Bbb R^\ell$ (with $\Bbb H^k$ the upper half space in $\Bbb R^k$), then the derivative is well-defined no matter what local smooth extension we take to an open subset of $\Bbb R^k$).

Comment: Why doesn't it make sense? I didn't take the differential on the boundary, I'm just saying that near it it isn't necessarily close to I, so I don't understand why would the pullback is continuous on the boundary? Furthermore, here we don't have charts - we have r, which can't necessarily be locally extended to a smooth function on an open neighbourhood of a point on $S^{n-1}$.

Comment: You need to relearn the basics. Whether you have explicit charts or not, it is by using charts that one defines things like the derivative of a mapping between manifolds. I'm not going to keep arguing with you. Last, $r$ maps an $n$-manifold (with boundary) to an $(n-1)$-manifold, so your statement that the limiting derivative should be the identity map is nonsense.

Comment: I'm very sorry if it came of as arguing with you, I am honestly trying to understand. It seems I'm not very proficient with derivative of functions between manifolds.
Also, I see now why what I said about the derivative is nonsense - sorry again.
I don't really know what to do with this post now? Delete my comments since they are misleading?

Comment: No need to delete. There's valuable information here. But you might want to read through Guillemin and Pollack or some other concrete treatment of manifolds.